# How to find serial port for mini-usb on beaglebone black?

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, beagleboneblack, tty, beagleboard

I'm working on a project for which I'm using beaglebone black which is connected via USB (on MAC) to Mini-USB (on beaglebone side).

So for me to read or write any data on the serial port on beaglebone side - I would need to know the port number. Is there any way I can find the TTY port assigned for MINI-USB? I know it's one among `/dev/tty`.

Thanks!

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ ls -l /dev/ | grep tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty       5,   2 Jun 17 16:08 ptmx
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty       5,   0 Jun 17 13:18 tty
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   0 Jun 17 13:18 tty0
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   1 Jun 17 13:18 tty1
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  10 Jun 17 13:18 tty10
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  11 Jun 17 13:18 tty11
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  12 Jun 17 13:18 tty12
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  13 Jun 17 13:18 tty13
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  14 Jun 17 13:18 tty14
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  15 Jun 17 13:18 tty15
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  16 Jun 17 13:18 tty16
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  17 Jun 17 13:18 tty17
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  18 Jun 17 13:18 tty18
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  19 Jun 17 13:18 tty19
```

Comment: try checking `dmesg` output. if possible post it here.

Answer (score 0):

**dmesg | grep serial**

will return something like:

```
44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 158, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
48022000.serial: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x48022000 (irq = 159, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
48024000.serial: ttyS2 at MMIO 0x48024000 (irq = 160, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
```

**cat /proc/tty/driver/serial**

will also provide useful information:

```
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:8250 mmio:0x44E09000 irq:158 tx:4380 rx:0 RTS|CTS|DTR|DSR
1: uart:8250 mmio:0x48022000 irq:159 tx:0 rx:0 CTS|DSR|CD|RI
2: uart:8250 mmio:0x48024000 irq:160 tx:0 rx:0 CTS|DSR
3: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
4: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
5: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
```

in both cases you will find out all active serial ports and will need to figure out which one you want to use.